# why my component is not display using react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I am trying to display  a `react-component` .I added some routing `mechanism` .but it not display my component.
here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/WnJl4DKOJ

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Hello from '../Hello';

const Routers = ()=> (
    <Route exact path="/" component={Hello}></Route>
)

export default Routers;
```

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Routers from './router/router';

const history = createHistory();


render(
      <Router routes={Routers} history={history}></Router>

  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using the `<Router />` properly. Make your `<Routers />` a child of `<Router />`.

In your example, change `<Router routes={Routers} history={history}></Router>` to:

```
<Router history={history}>
    <Routers />
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Router/>` provides the required context for the routes.

You need to modify your code as

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import Hello from '../Hello';

const Routers = ()=> (
    <Router>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Hello}/>
    </Router>
)

export default Routers;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import {Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Routers from './router/router';

const history = createHistory();


render(<Routers history={history}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```